# Is uiautomator compatible with Windows, Linux and MacOS?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I can't find an answer on http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html#api

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**`uiautomator`** tests run on the Android device or emulator, not on the development machine. Hence, it runs on Android, not Windows, Linux, or OS X.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is regarding development of the script, `uiautomator` comes along with android sdk and is supported on Windows, Linux, or OS X.

But the tests can be validated only on `Andoid mobile (API 16 or higher)` as suggested by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)

Source: [Link](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html)